# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to run a Pytorch program on Jupyter Notebook, and keep running into an error. Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim


REBUILD_DATA = False # set to true to one once, then back to false unless you want to change something in your training data.

class DogsVSCats():
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    #CATS = "PetImages/Cat"
    #DOGS = "PetImages/Dog"
    #TESTING = "PetImages/Testing"
    CATS = r"C:\Users\ziyaahmad\Downloads\aluminum_cans"
    DOGS = r"C:\Users\ziyaahmad\Downloads\plastic_bottles"
    LABELS = {CATS: 0, DOGS: 1}
    training_data = []

    catcount = 0
    dogcount = 0

    def make_training_data(self):
        for label in self.LABELS:
            print(label)
            for f in tqdm(os.listdir(label)):
                if "jpg" in f:
                    try:
                        path = os.path.join(label, f)
                        img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.IMG_SIZE, self.IMG_SIZE))
                        self.training_data.append([np.array(img), np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]]])  # do something like print(np.eye(2)[1]), just makes one_hot 
                        #print(np.eye(2)[self.LABELS[label]])

                        if label == self.CATS:
                            self.catcount += 1
                        elif label == self.DOGS:
                            self.dogcount += 1

                    except Exception as e:
                        pass
                        #print(label, f, str(e))

        np.random.shuffle(self.training_data)
        np.save("training_data.npy", self.training_data)
        print('Cats:',dogsvcats.catcount)
        print('Dogs:',dogsvcats.dogcount)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(50,50).view(-1,1,50,50)
        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 2)

    def convs(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), (2,2))

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]*x[0].shape[2]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)



if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")  # you can continue going on here, like cuda:1 cuda:2....etc. 
    print("Running on the GPU")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("Running on the CPU")




net = Net().to(device)

if REBUILD_DATA:
    dogsvcats = DogsVSCats()
    dogsvcats.make_training_data()

training_data = np.load("training_data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
print(len(training_data))

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()

X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data]).view(-1, 50, 50)
X = X/255.0
y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])

VAL_PCT = 0.1
val_size = int(len(X)*VAL_PCT)
print(val_size)

train_X = X[:-val_size]
train_y = y[:-val_size]

test_X = X[-val_size:]
test_y = y[-val_size:]

print(len(train_X))
print(len(test_X))


def train(net):
    BATCH_SIZE = 150
    EPOCHS = 2
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE)):
            batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1,1,50,50)
            batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

            batch_X, batch_y = batch_X.to(device), batch_y.to(device)

            net.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(batch_X)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        print(loss)

def test(net):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in tqdm(range(len(test_X))):
            real_class = torch.argmax(test_y[i]).to(device)
            net_out = net(test_X[i].view(-1, 1, 50, 50).to(device))[0]

            predicted_class = torch.argmax(net_out)
            if predicted_class == real_class:
                correct += 1
            total += 1
    print("Accuracy:", round(correct/total,3))


def fwd_pass(X, y, train=False): #data validation
    if train:
        net.zero_grad() #sets gradients of all parameters to zero
    outputs = net(X) #passing X
    matches = [torch.argmax(i) == torch.argmax(j) for i, j in zip(outputs, y)]
    #acc = matches.count(True)/len*(matches) #will return percentage accuracy
    acc = matches.count(True) / len(matches) * 100  # Calculate accuracy as a percentage
    loss = loss_function(outputs, y)
    if train:
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() #updates models parameters (weights, biases, etc)
    return acc, loss

def test(size=32):
    random_start = np.random.randint(len(test_X)-size)
    X, y = test_X[random_start:random_start+size], test_y[random_start:random_start+size]
    with torch.no_grad():
        val_acc, val_loss = fwd_pass(X.view(-1,1,50,50).to(device), y.to(device))
    return val_acc, val_loss

val_acc, val_loss = test(size=32)
print(val_acc, val_loss)
```

When I run this program, it returns this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 8
      5         val_acc, val_loss = fwd_pass(X.view(-1,1,50,50).to(device), y.to(device))
      6     return val_acc, val_loss
----> 8 val_acc, val_loss = test(size=32)
      9 print(val_acc, val_loss)

Cell In[10], line 5, in test(size)
      3 X, y = test_X[random_start:random_start+size], test_y[random_start:random_start+size]
      4 with torch.no_grad():
----> 5     val_acc, val_loss = fwd_pass(X.view(-1,1,50,50).to(device), y.to(device))
      6 return val_acc, val_loss

Cell In[9], line 8, in fwd_pass(X, y, train)
      6 #acc = matches.count(True)/len*(matches) #will return percentage accuracy
      7 acc = matches.count(True) / len(matches) * 100  # Calculate accuracy as a percentage
----> 8 loss = loss_function(outputs, y)
      9 if train:
     10     loss.backward()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:536, in MSELoss.forward(self, input, target)
    535 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 536     return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3294, in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   3291 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3292     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3294 expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
   3295 return torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\functional.py:74, in broadcast_tensors(*tensors)
     72 if has_torch_function(tensors):
     73     return handle_torch_function(broadcast_tensors, tensors, *tensors)
---> 74 return _VF.broadcast_tensors(tensors)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I've tried adding in multiple print statements into my program (i put one to print self.LABELS[label]), and used .shape to check the size of np.eye(2). I put both of these statements after line 35.